# Allow for acrylic to be not turned off when focus is lost from app?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

Acrylic is by far the best thing in fluent design system, it just makes the app looks so good. And I am totally fine with optimization of it; turning of the transparency when battery is in saving mode.

But I don't want it to be turned off when the user looses the focus over the app. Is there any workarounds for it?

[image: UWP app]

When the user looses the focus over the app, acrylic is turned off and fallback color is used!

[image: UWP app]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately acrylic background effect is currently limited to run only when the application window is active, as stated [in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/style/acrylic#usability-and-adaptability)

> In addition, only background acrylic will replace its transparency and texture with a solid color
>
> **When an app window on desktop deactivates**
>
> When the UWP app is running on phone, Xbox, HoloLens or tablet mode

Comment: No worries, it will roll out sometime in the future!

Comment: @AlishanKhan it will actually go away before it will be supported properly... (the window acrylic option will not be available in the first version of WinUI)